# Android/ phonegap - Click response time slow

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, timer

I am close to working out a solution courtesy of ghostCoder hinting at the idea of detecting the touch event rather than the click event. This below code is what I currently have, however something is still not quite right. It works on my homepage (very basic page), however with the actual game page it breaks:

Here is my code:
JAVASCRIPT:

```
var b=document.getElementById('STOP'),start=0;

//Check for touchstart
if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) 
{
    document.getElementById("notouchstart").style.display = "none";
}

//Add a listener that fires at the beginning of each interaction
[b].forEach(function(el){el.addEventListener('touchstart',interact);});

//Add the event handlers for each button
b.addEventListener('touchstart',highlight);

//Functions Store the time when the user initiated an action
function interact(e) 
{
    start = new Date();
}

//Highlight what the user selected and calculate how long it took the action to occur
function highlight(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.className="active";
    if(start)
    {
        alert("test")
    }
    start = null;
}
```

BODY BUTTONS (firstly displays start button then when clicked displays stop button, then start again etc.)

```
    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background:url(images/Start_Btn.png); background-color:transparent; width:150px; height:186px; border:none; cursor:pointer;" id="START" onClick="startBTN();">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background:url(images/Stop_Btn.png); background-color:transparent; width:150px; height:186px; border:none; cursor:pointer;" id="STOP">
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can probably reduce the delay a lot by skipping phonegap. Phonegap just adds another layer between the system and the user, slowing down things more than neccessary, and when it comes to a "simple" application such as this, you'll probably be best of programming it once for each platform.

Comment: The issue there is I have created the whole app and functionality inc validation etc in html and javascript. Therefore, implementing this with Java would be starting from scratch. On top of this my Java skill sare still very limited. Any other solutions?

Comment: In that case - not really. Not without seeing any code at least, and even then I am not that proficient in JS. Just optimize as much as you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for ‘touchstart’ instead of ‘click'   :) 
 click is a bit delayed in touchscreens.
http://floatlearning.com/2011/03/developing-better-phonegap-apps/

Comment: Looks like this might be along the lines of what i am looking for, however how can i implement this with my input buttons? I have edited my question with the HTML code for these buttons.

Comment: read that article.
u need to bind the input to the touchstart event and do things in that handler

Comment: I am almost there have tested it and worked fine, however when trying to implement it my code seems to be breaking at the [b].forEach(function(el){el.addEventListener('touchstart',interact);}); section, any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Have edited my orginal question with my new code, both javascript and HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I have used `touchend` for this. `touchstart` is being triggered even though the action is `drag/scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use buttons. If you add the event to a div it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a calculator and my first idea was to start with phonegap. Now I strongly recommend not to do that when button presses are time critical. Even with disabling all extra touch handlers and setting touchstart directly to the div: it's just too slow. (touchend won't do by the way, it's called when you release the finger from the button)

Answer (score 0):

In a Phonegap application the click event have a 300ms of delay time. Why don't you use Fastclick library for this pourpose??? I have tried it and works great!

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Hope is helpful